# Pricing a structured note instrument

Tags: fixed-income, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to work out the following fixed income problem, where I am asked to price a structured note in Excel, which seems to me to be a reverse collar. 
My purpose was replicating this structured note through a long and a short cap and consequently using the Black formula for cap. 
However I do not have enough inputs, since volatility and strike price are unknown to me. 
Moreover, since my trade date is a given day in 2013, the maturity date is very long (2029) and I should compute the price of too many caplets. 
As a result, the choice of caps as replicating instruments is not the better one. **Could I replicate this stuctured note in an alternative way, maybe using coupon bonds, whose price is known to me?** 
How can I implement this idea in Excel? 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What is so difficult about calculating the value of 32 caplets?

Comment: I don't understand the issue either.

Comment: It is the first time I solve this exercise, so I apologize for asking a question that maybe it is simple.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw I was just asking if there exist another simpler (and maybe faster) strategy to replicate this structured  note.

Comment: @noob2 Aren't caplets 30, if I assume that the first Euribor rate is not stochastic?

Comment: Sorry, I did not count exactly. You have the exact start and end dates, I don't.

Comment: @noob2 Sorry, but if the frequency of payments of this structured note is semi-annual, shouldn't I replicate this by picking semiannual caplets too? (Shouldn't I get 30+30 caplets?)